# define string in numba @jitclass

Tags: python, oop, numba

Trying to JIT one of my classes . No problem with ints, floats, or arrays . But having trouble when it comes to setting a string attr .

```
from numba import *

spec = [ ('symb',char)] ## define symb as a char

@jitclass(spec)
class trade_jit:

    def __init__(self, symb):
        print(symb)      ## this works
        self.symb = symb ## this doesn't
```

If I only have the print statement, it works .

When the self.symb = symb is incorporated, it says :

```
File "<string>", line 3:
<source missing, REPL/exec in use?>
```

Desired output would be to be able to set string attributes when using @jitclass.

Comment: How are you running this code?  A standard python interactive shell, or an IDE, or something else?

Comment: @JohnGordon running in jupyter

Comment: @thomas.mac Were you able to solve it?

Comment: @florestan you need to convert it to bits , and then back to a string using .encode()

Comment: @thomas.mac could you elaborate a bit more on your answer. What is it that needs to be converted to bits and so on???